# I want my python tool to have a mechanism like whenever anyone runs the tool a pop up should come up as New version available please use the latest

Tags: python, python-3.x

I Have created a python based tool for my teammates, Where we group all the similar JIRA tickets and hence it becomes easier to pick the priority one first. But the problem is every time I make some changes I have to ask people to get the latest one from the Perforce server. So I am looking for a mechanism where whenever anyone uses the tool a pop up should come up as "New version available" please install.

Can anyone help how to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

On startup, or periodically while running, you could have the tool query your Perforce server and check the latest version. If it doesn't match the version currently running, then you would show the popup, and maybe provide a download link.

I'm not personally familiar with Perforce, but in Git for example you could check the hash of the most recent commit. You could even just include a file with a version number that you manually increment every time you push changes.

Answer (score 2):

I have an idea,you can use requests module to crawl your website(put the number of version in the page) and get the newest version.
And then,get the version in the user's computer and compare to the official version.If different or lower than official version,Pop a window to remind user to update

Answer (score 1):

You could maintain the latest version code/tool on your server and have your tool check it periodically against its own version code. If the version code is higher on the server, then your tool needs to be updated and you can tell the user accordingly or raise appropriate pop-up recommending for an update.